# Spring's SimpleJdbcTemplate and loading SQL scripts

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc

I have a DAO with many methods, each containing an SQL statement to execute. I don't want to hard code SQL strings into the DAO Java class so what's the best way of managing this scenario? I am thinking of injecting them, but how best to do this?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Why don't you want to put the SQL in the DAO - it's the most logical place, and who else is going to need it?  It makes JDBC code much easier to read if you can see the queries.

Comment: I agree but it feels wrong to put in lots of SQL into the code when I could load it from file and inject it, which would make **minor** tweaks to SQL easier for the DBA.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a DBA to have any input to the business logic, and that's what you are writing in a DAO, so I don't see the conflict there.  There are plenty of options if you want to externalize the Strings, but I disagree that it is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: (Correction: I disagree that it is the _right_ thing to do.  Duh!)

Comment: Thanks Dave, and again I agree with you. I guess I'm looking for the generally accepted method and if this is it then I'll stop feeling so conflicted about doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject your SQL statements during application initialization.

```
class MyDAO {
   private String someQuery;

   public void setSomeQuery(String someQuery) {
       this.someQuery = someQuery;
   }

}
```

Then you can have your SQL statments in XML file, not hardcoded.

```
<bean class="some.package.MyDAO">
    <property name="someQuery">
        <value>
            SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can even externalize your SQL statements to `.properties` files.

Take a look: http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/

Comment: +1 for realy nice answer. by the way... you forgott the return type of setSomeQuery.

Comment: Thanks. Stack Overflow is like Wikipedia :-) You could've corrected my mistake by yourself :) Now it's fixed.